# Application for different versions and different resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am in middle of learning application development.

I have created an application in 2.2 and tested that in my HTC Nexus One device.

I looks like fine. My client testing same application setup in his device (Droid2). I don't have that device to test.

He said there are some font sizes are vary and button alignments are missing. When I testing in my device everything looks fine.

So, I need to test my application in Simulator which resembles like Droid2 device. Can anyone tell me how to create emulator and setup like Droid2.

And also, is there any need to adjust my code or anything in manifest file.

Any help/suggestion will be much helpful for me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/ and download the emulator add-ons for any of the Motorola android family.  Droid 2, Droid X, Cliq, Devour, all your favorites.

I cant comment on your code because I have not seen it.